# use macro for multiple workbooks

Tags: vba, generics, save, send

I have created a few macros for a set of actions.

The code are pretty generic since I want to use them for a general purpose (to automatic copy and paste some worksheets within the same workbook).

I wonder what and how to save the macros so that I can send it out to my colleagues and let them use the codes for other workbooks?

Should I save it as a macro enabled workbook and let my colleages import their own worksheets?

Comment: is it VBA which you made your macros?

Comment: yes. It is actually the macros you helped me with earlier @KazJaw.  I am looking for a way which my colleagues can use the macros as well for the whole project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** You could create add-in in Excel, the file with `*.xlam` extension. Then you need to sent that file to them. Your colleagues will need to open it to save it as add-in.

**2)** You can export your module where your vba code is to `*.bas` file as presented on the picture below. Than you colleagues need to import it to their files. Right-click on your module in VBE editor to get this menu where you'll find Export and Import options.

[image]

**3)** You could simply copy your code and send it by e-mail. Add instruction which way your colleagues will add modules where they paste your code. They could use `Personal.xlsb` as a destination file for your macros.

Comment: Thanks!! That is very helpful! For the first option, do my colleagues need to save the add-in once or everytime when they open up a different workbook?

Comment: they will need to save this file once and they will be able to use it each time Excel will start. However, it could be required to make additional settings in Excel-App in Menu >> File >> Options >> Add-ins...

Comment: Thanks again. I think adding add-ins will be the best option since I will be leaving the group soon and I hope them to be able to use and add onto the vba macros. :)